# Update Sqlite column according to insertion

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have 3 tables, med_list, med_receive and med_issue.

`med_list`

```
   -----------------------------------
   | med_id | med_name | med_balance |
   -----------------------------------
```

`med_receive` (`med_amount` is the amount received):

```
   -----------------------------------
   | med_id | med_batch | med_amount |
   -----------------------------------
```

`med_issue` (`med_amount` here is the amount issued):

```
   -----------------------
   | med_id | med_amount |
   -----------------------
```

Now the `med_balance` in table `med_list` should be equal to `sum of received med - sum of issued med`.

The user directly adds into the `receive` and `issue` table.

My question is: can I automate the update of the `med_balance` for all med?

For example:

Let's say we have med with name `X` and its balance is `0`. If the user enters a receive of 100 tablets for that med, the `med_balance` should automatically be updated to `100`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to keep a calculated value in your database? That's usually a pretty bad idea that goes against good database design standards.

Comment: @TomH 
thanku for answering, ok is there anyother way i can solve this problem?

Comment: Get the calculation from the database whenever you need it, from the sources using aggregate functions, such as SUM().

Answer (score 0):

write a before insert trigger on the driving table.
In the Before Insert trigger update the value.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter in this case (as shown), but would an AFTER INSERT be better in general (in case the insertion should fail for any reason)?

Comment: @TripeHound tried AFTER INSERT it works for me. thanks